# Comma-separated list valid in Content-Type header?

Tags: http, http-headers, rss, mime-types, simplepie

An RSS feed [provider](https://feed.businesswire.com/rss/home/?rss=G1QFDERJXkJeEFpQWg==) recently started sending this in its response headers:

```
Content-type: application/rss+xml, text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

To support this provider, I needed to change a line in a feed integration package ([SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/))

1. Is the provider "wrong?"
2. Would it be "wrong" to change a community-maintained package to support this header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - Content-Type doesn't take a list. Apparently somebody confused "Content-Type" with "Accept".
2. Yes.